# Python: How to set up configuration variables of program?

Tags: python

I'm writing a script that takes a directory as input. This directory will be used by many different functions which read data from the disk. Currently, the directory name is stored in a variable, which is passed through to each function or class that uses it:

```
data_dir = get_data_dir()
spam = calculate_spam(foo, bar, data_directory=data_dir)
eggs = calculate_eggs(spam, baz, data_directory=data_dir)
```

Unfortunately, the function signatures and function calls get quite long, which makes the code unnecessarily hard to read and therefore error-prone. Is there a better (i.e. Pythonic) way handling configuration parameters like this?

Comment: You can have them in [config](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/configparser.html) file(s), and pass the confing object(s) or parts of it around. You can also have single module, like myconf.py and use it for configuration parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a bunch of functions who share many required arguments, such as:

```
foo(x, y, z, alpha)
bar(x, y, z, beta)
baz(x, y, z, gamma)
```

It *can* be a sign that `x`, `y`, and `z` belong in a dictionary or namedtuple together. You might go this route and place the parts of your configuration that go together into a namedtuple. But note that you generally only want to pass *exactly what is needed* into a function, and no more. So if your functions are taking a dictionary with a bunch of configuration parameters just to use a single entry, it might be a sign of bad design.

It might even make sense to put `x`, `y`, and `z` in a class, and make `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` methods:

```
class XYZ:

    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        ...

    def foo(self, alpha):
        ...

    def bar(self, beta):
        ...

    def baz(self, gamma):
        ...
```

The configuration then becomes part of the state of your class.

On the other hand, long argument lists can be a sign that your function does more than it needs to. Consider your function, `calculate_spam(foo, bar, data_dir)`. Presumably, this function loads some data from a directory and computes some data. Would it make more sense to separate the loading and the computing into two separate functions, such as `load_spam(data_dir)` to load the data, then `calculate_spam(data, ...)` to calculate it?

I often find that when I have too many arguments, I just need to split the function into smaller pieces. It's not a law, but a rule of thumb that works a lot of the time for me.

Comment: You are right, the function appears to be doing multiple things. In my actual code, the loading and the calculation are separated between two functions. The high-level function that is called manages all that (granted, the function names in my examples above are badly chosen). I am rather looking for a way to hide the configuration in some sort of global variable. Like the `logging` package, which one sets up in the beginning and then it available from everywhere without explicitly passing it around.

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a single list parameter for each function, if that makes it easier.